# James mail server Exception while delivering a message

Tags: java, apache, james

I am using the James mail server. The version is James-2.3.2. It can send to some servers, and to others it can't, which makes me very upset. 
Can send mail to accounts on localhost. The server is in Shanghai, China.
Send to outlook.com to throw the following exception

```
James.Mailet: RemoteDelivery: Exception delivering message(Mail1538212657969-14-to-outlook.com) - [EOF]
James.Mailet: RemoteDelivery: Temporary exception delivering mail (Mail1538212657969-14-to-outlook.com: 
James.Mailet: RemoteDelivery: Storing message Mail1538212657969-14-to-outlook.com into outgoing after 2 retries
```

Config.xml, I only configured DNS server.

```
<dnsserver>
  <servers>
     <!--Enter ip address of your DNS server, one IP address per server -->
     <server>183.xx.xx.19</server>
     <server>183.xx.xx.98</server>
  </servers>
  <!-- Change autodiscover to false if you would like to turn off autodiscovery -->
  <!-- and set the DNS servers manually in the <servers> section -->
  <autodiscover>false</autodiscover>
  <authoritative>false</authoritative>
  <!-- Maximum number of entries to maintain in the DNS cache -->
  <maxcachesize>50000</maxcachesize>
```

Comment: It works OK only on localhost or can you send email OK to mail servers like Gmail, yahoo etc'?

Comment: have you checked the RemoteAddrNotInNetwork mailet?

Comment: RemoteAddrNotInNetwork mailet Already annotated.Sending mail to GAMIL is successful, domestic 163.com, qq.com can be sent, Yahoo has not tried.

Comment: “Exception delivering message”，It may be the problem of receiving server's rejection or the configuration of my own server gateway.

Comment: feels to me it is outlook.com rejecting your email. Shutdown the server and clear all the logs from the logs folder. Then open the server and send an email to this address. Do you see anything in the logs other than this exception?

Comment: James.Mailet: RemoteDelivery: Attempting delivery of Mail1539160851367-0-to-outlook.com to host outlook-com.olc.protection.outlook.com. at 104.47.1.33 for addresses [zengrong4java@outlook.com]
 James.Mailet: RemoteDelivery: Exception delivering message (Mail1539160851367-0-to-outlook.com) - [EOF]
10/10/18 16:40:53 INFO  James.Mailet: RemoteDelivery: Temporary exception delivering mail (Mail1539160851367-0-to-outlook.com: 
James.Mailet: RemoteDelivery: Storing message Mail1539160851367-0-to-outlook.com into outgoing after 0 retries，This is a complete diary.

Comment: Is there any solution?

Comment: it seems that oulook.com will not accept email from you. The log does not give any reason for it. Sorry can't help more than that.